# Should exchange or queue be declared multiple times in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I discuss the `RabbitMQ` design with my colleague between `Server A` and `Server B`, here is the flow chart as following.

[image]

`Server A` sends messages to `Server B` through `exchange A` and `Queue B`, and receives messages from `Server B` through `Queue A`. vice versa for `Server B`.

There are two classes in `Server A` implemented with `C++`; one is `sender`, the other is `receiver`. The same code structure is for `Server B` implemented with `JavaScript`.

For the `sender` and `receiver` in `Server A`. My colleague's idea is:

- The initialization in Sender:

  - create connection with `rabbitmq`
  - declare the `exchange A`
  - declare the `Queue B`
  - bind the key to `Queue B`
- The initialization in Receiver:

  - create connection with `rabbitmq`
  - declare the `exchange B`
  - declare the `Queue A`
  - bind the key to `Queue A`

The same logic in `Server B`.

However, I **do NOT think `Queue B` and `Exchange B` should be declared in `Server A`. They are should be declared in `Server B`.**

Finally, I implement it following my colleague's idea, due to he has done some  related work before.

---

Today, the `Server A` **hang** at the function `amqp_queue_declare` in `Sender` module during test, but it works well after restarting `RabbitMQ`. So I doubt the my colleague's idea for the initialization of `Sender`.

My thought:

- `Server A`

  - The initialization in Sender

    - create connection with `rabbitmq`
    - declare the `Exchange A`
  - The initialization in Receiver

    - create connection with `rabbitmq`
    - create the `Queue A`
    - bind the key to `Queue A`
- `Server B`

  - The initialization in Sender

    - create connection with `rabbitmq`
    - declare the `Exchange B`
  - The initialization in Receiver

    - create connection with `rabbitmq`
    - create the `Queue B`
    - bind the key to `Queue B`

Could someone tell me is there anything wrong with my thought? or is there better solution?

---

**Edit**: answer questions from @Sigismondo

- *do all the messages need to be delivered to the consumer A/B?*

  No
- *does the consumer A/B need to be notified in case some messages are lost?*

  No. I want to know how could consumer A know there is message lost?
- *what is the intended behavior in case the consumer A/B is not reachable?*

  If consumer A is not reachable, then producer B will not sent any message to A, and vise versa. **How could B know the consumer A is not reachable??**

  Currently, in my system, there is ack for every message. so B does not get ack from A in the previous case, then B will not sent message to A.
- *what is the intended behavior in case the producer A/B is down?*

  If producer B is down, then A will not receive any message from B. So A will not send any message to B.

Comment: "Currently, in my system, there is ack for every message". Do you mean RabbitMQ/AMQP standard ack, isn't it?

Comment: @Sigismondo Not the amqp standard ack, the ack message defined in my own system.

Comment: I see. Couldn't your problem be classified as "RPC-over-messaging", as shown here for example? https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Comment: Yes, `RPC` is also used in my system

Comment: From what I can guess here, it seems to me that you want to couple producer and consumer, when messaging aim is the opposite: decouple producer and consumer. So you can let a request be put on the requests queue even if the consumer is not there, and it can consume it and put the response on the responses queue even if there is the consumer there (the original requestor)

Comment: (not "there is the consumer there", but "there isn't the consumer there")

Answer (score 11):

It's perfectly legit that both servers declare the queue and the exchange, and it's usually the preferred approach, when dealing with named queues: *usually* you want producers and consumers be decoupled, and letting both declare (i.e.: create if missing) the queues and the exchange, you let both work correctly and you have the guarantee that no messages are lost, in case the other peer has not been started yet, even on a RabbitMQ fresh install.

In particular it's important that:

- the consumer declare the queues from which must consume messages (or it won't be able to consume from them).
- the producer declare the queues **and** the exchanges to which it produces **before** producing messages (or they will be lost, in case no consumer has created the queues).

This is the typical approach used when using named queues, that seems what you are doing here.

Now, in case you want the messages to be forgotten in case the consumer is not there, than the producer won't declare any queue: the consumer can create a [temporary queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) and bind it to the exchange.

Finally, if this is the case, and you want to be notified in case there are not consumers (and no queues bound to the exchange), you can use [alternate exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html).

So, you see it: there are some options that you can use, but there is a rationale for each one: you must choose which one to use based on the specific problem - and that has not been qualified enough by your explanation: even if very detailed it's missing some aspects:

- do all the messages need to be delivered to the consumer A/B?
- does the consumer A/B need to be notified in case some messages are lost?
- what is the intended behavior in case the consumer A/B is not reachable?
- what is the intended behavior in case the producer A/B is down?

However `amqp_queue_declare` should not hang at all: if this is the case you are facing a bug or I have no idea what, but that's not the intended behavior for it, to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have answered your question in my quesiton